# using LocalConnection with .swf in CEF embed inside Open Broadcaster

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, chromium, chromium-embedded, localconnection

I'm attempting to use two SWF files to render, animate, and control the overlays for a video stream being produced in Open Broadcaster. The control panel SWF sits outside the application in a standalone projector, and the rendering .swf is placed inside the stream by adding it as the source media file for a plugin that uses CEF3 to create a browser window.

When these two files are in standalone media players, they communicate fine, however the setup described above is preventing this functionality from working properly. I know that both .swf files have all domains and insecure domains allowed, the CEF plugin is using the NPAPI Flash 12.0.0 player instead of the PPAPI 'pepper' player (which has additional security restrictions directly blocking LocalConnection), and I'm even able to socket with the rendering .swf and receive data through Monster Debugger. However, I'm at a loss as to how to step through what is preventing LocalConnection from communicating.

All of the guides and information I've found on this issue in regards to Chromium have been specifically about getting around the PPAPI restrictions, and state that the NPAPI should work fine. However, I'm concerned that the two layers of hosting (The CEF browser window and the Open Broadcaster app itself) is just not a scenario where this methodology is possible.

Comment: What's your question, exactly?

Comment: My question is attempting to ascertain what is it about this setup that's preventing it from successfully connecting, when every document I've found online either states that it *should* work, or doesn't cover this use case. If an .swf file is running on the same client as another, but is rendered inside a CEF window being called inside another application, what obstacles do I need to clear in order for it to see over the wall and make a successful connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this: Adding the folder containing the .swf files to the Trusted Sources list inside Flash's Global Settings. Wasn't documented anywhere in relation to the security settings that effect LocalConnection so it wasn't an obvious fix. Once I did this, the files communicated fine.

The follow-up question is why this is required when one is inside CEF/OBS, and not when they're both in Standalone players, but I'll take the fact that it works for now. :)